# $\bar{\partial}$-exact vs $d$-exact Kähler form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,I,\omega)$ be a non-compact Kähler manifold. What is the relationship between the following two properties?

- $\omega$ is $\bar{\partial}$-exact.
- $\omega$ is $d$-exact.

Are they equivalent, or does one imply the other?

Answer (score 2):

In Hideaki Kazama and Shigeharu Takayama's book *Recent Developments in Complex Analysis and Computer Algebra* Chapter 13 **$\partial \bar\partial$-lemma on Noncompact and Kähler Manifolds**.

They prove $\partial \bar\partial$ theorem  holds for toroidal groups of cohomologically finite type and that it does not hold for toroidal groups of non-Hausdorff type,that is:

[image]
[image]

You can read more details in that chapter.